Is EMT plenum rated? If I install EMT in a plenum and run general purpose wiring through it, does this violate NFPA 75?
I have a raised floor area with a few server racks on top, the under floor area is used to distribute HVAC to the racks. I have already run all the cables before learning of NFPA75's plenum rating requirement. I'm really struggling to find any plenum rated conduit/raceway with a larger than 2 inch inner diameter. My main question is... is EMT considered plenum rated? I think it is, but more specifically, can I run general purpose wiring through an EMT in a plenum and still meet standards? If I can't do this, any suggestions on sources for plenum raceway/conduit with 3, 4, and 5" inner diameter sizes?

This isn't an electrical design question, it's a materials question.

This question would be better in the Home Improvement/DIY stack as there are many people there very familiar with the Electrical Code.

Though DIY is for home improvement only. This sounds like it might be an enterprise question which they will tell you to pay someone for their expertise.

Do you even need a covered raceway? isn't the floor enough?

your cooling air supply flows under the floor?
